# How to make div height compatible on every browser

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a page where i have a header, footer and content divs. the header is 140px in height, footer 90px. What i want is to make the content div in between header and footer and should be seen in the same way in all browsers.

all browsers height is different therefore to adjust this content div how can i style it? i have a hunch that is using bottom and top in css. help me through it.

Answer (score -1):

If your problem are different sizes on every browser, try using a [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Other option could be setting the [`box-sizing` to `border-box`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```